# How can I solve LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have checked all examples related to this but have not been able to solve my issue.

I have created check box and if I used to unchecked means getting some values

It return

```
string selectedid = {"2","6","45","34","5"};  
string[] separteid = Regex.Split(selectedid, ",");

List<string>idlist=new List<string>();
foreach(var item in separteid)
{
     idlist.Add(item);
}
```

I want to check with integer ID of database table

```
job = (from n in bc.db.xx where idlist.Contains(n.id.ToString()) select n);
ViewBag.Count = job.Count();
```

How to fix it? Anyone help?

Comment: you can't use ToString() method in linq to sql since it's not a DbFunction

Comment: And why you need to make a string array since you have all integer values ?

Comment: I used to compare all values with string format

Comment: So what is the type of `n.id`? It sounds like it's `string`, in which case why are you calling `ToString()` at all?

Comment: @Abila what is the type of n.id ?

Comment: n.id is Integer type

Answer (score 3):

You can use following if EF version being used is 4 or above. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) for more.

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Decimal)n.id).Trim(),
```

Or else you can convert your list of string into list of int like below and use .Contains over it.

```
job = (from n in bc.db.xx where idlist.Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).Contains(n.id) select n);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `typeof (n.id) == System.String`, just remove the `ToString()` invocation. If the type is int, or something implicitly convertible to an int, transform your list instead:

```
string[] strIds = new[] {"1", "2", "3"}; // I assume you get these values from somewhere else
var idlist = strIds.Select(int.Parse);
var job = (from n in bc.db.xx
           where idlist.Contains(n.id.ToString())
           select n);
```

Answer (score 2):

A very fix in your case since you're comparing against integers on the DB side would be to pass integers on the C# side instead of passing strings and trying to convert on the other side

The issue is that most of your code doesn't make sense, you're creating a string with list syntax (i'm surprised this even compiles). Then make it into an array by spliting it, then generate a list from that array, all of this could be done in a single step, or better yet you could even declare as a list of int to begin with replacing all of this :

```
string selectedid = {"2","6","45","34","5"};  
string[] separteid = Regex.Split(selectedid, ",");

List<string>idlist=new List<string>();
foreach(var item in separteid)
{
     idlist.Add(item);
}
```

with this:

```
List<int> idlist = new List<int>(){2,6,45,34,5};
```

And then you already have the right type which allows you to simplify this :

```
job = (from n in bc.db.xx where idlist.Contains(n.id.ToString()) select n);
ViewBag.Count = job.Count();
```

To this :

```
ViewBag.Count = (from n in bc.db.xx where idlist.Contains(n.id) select n)
    .Count();
```

Or if you don't mind lambda syntax you can directly pass the predicate to count:

```
ViewBag.Count = bc.db.xx
    .Count(n=>idlist.Countains(n.id));
```